# How do we improve the performance of a react application which renders the the deep nested tree data with a recursive component

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a react application, where we will receive the data from API in a tree structure format like below. (The maximum no of nodes that the API can return are ~30000 including leaf/child/all nodes)

[JSON sample response](https://jsonblob.com/76ee90ba-1c66-11eb-92fc-afc1c3197baa)

I have developed a recursive react functional component to render the data with some sort of styling based on the tree structure entity type (like a paragraph, author, year, etc). Which looks like below.

```js
function Recursive({ articleContent }) {
  switch (articleContent.type) {
    case ENTITY_TYPES.TITLE:
      return (
        <h3 style={{ textTransform: "capitalize" }}>{articleContent.title}</h3>
      );
    case ENTITY_TYPES.PARAGRAPH:
      return (
        <div>
          <p>{articleContent.data}</p>
        </div>
      );
    case ENTITY_TYPES.AUTHOR:
      return (
        <span style={{ alignSelf: "flex-end", marginRight: "20px" }}>
          {articleContent.author}
        </span>
      );
    case ENTITY_TYPES.IMAGE:
      return (
        <img
          src={articleContent.url}
          alt="img"
          style={{ width: 100, height: 100 }}
        />
      );
    case ENTITY_TYPES.YEAR:
      return (
        <span style={{ border: "1px solid grey", padding: 5 }}>
          {articleContent.year.toString()}
        </span>
      );
    case ENTITY_TYPES.QUOTE:
      return (
        <blockquote
          style={{
            background: "#f9f9f9",
            borderLeft: "10px solid #ccc",
            margin: "1.5em 10px",
            padding: "0.5em 10px"
          }}
        >
          {articleContent.quote}
        </blockquote>
      );
    case ENTITY_TYPES.CHILD:
      return articleContent.child.map((_leafNode, i) => {
        return <Recursive key={i} articleContent={_leafNode} />;
      });
    default:
      return null;
  }
}
```

The react application is just working as expected without any flaws.
The problem I'm facing is, when we have large data nodes from the API, the rendering is taking so long. Is there any way to overcome this sort of problem?

Could someone help me with this!!

Here is the [CodeSandBox](https://codesandbox.io/s/agitated-minsky-9h6eb?file=/src/App.js), which has some mock API call with mock data response.

Try changing the below value and see the rendering delays

```js
// Change the no of articles here and see the rendering time
const NO_OF_ARTICLES = 2; 
// to something
const NO_OF_ARTICLES = 5000;
```

- I have tried to implement react memorization techniques (of course the memorization not required in this application, as there are no frequent state/prop changes). But I don't see any improvement while rendering the data.
- Nextjs is not the best solution for this application (due to some limitations)

PS: Ignore typos / grammar

Comment: Maybe I help you. I would recommend to use virtualize render. I hope  this one can help. https://github.com/bvaughn/react-virtualized

Comment: @KirillSkomarovskiy I have this as the last alternative. The navigation within the DOM might face some problems, as all the content (with element ids) will not be rendered until and unless the user scrolls the page! Correct me If I'm wrong.

Comment: I’m not familiar with react-virtualized well. But I think it’s true.

Comment: a quick a dirty fix to this would be to use an above the fold component and below the fold component. Above the fold would query a subset of data whlle below the fold would aquire the remaining elements. You could then investigate the use of [<Suspense>](https://reactjs.org/docs/concurrent-mode-suspense.html)

Comment: As per my knowledge <Suspense/>, will have some fallback (provided by us) and can be useful if we are doing something that will take more time to render the results. And the application that I have shared above does not have any dealy from the network, the data just returned in just 0.5 ms (with real-time data & real servers). So even Lazy or Suspense doesn't address the performance bottleneck that my application is facing

Answer (score 0):

What if you lazy render the child?
That is Wrap the child in a component that has button which when clicked renders the `<Recursive />` component

```
<More>
 <Recursive />
</More>
```

```
//more component render method
render (){
   if(this.state.show){
    return this.props.children
   }
 // show a button or something else 
   return <Button 
         onClick={()=> this.setState({show: true})}
        label="View More" />
}
```

Comment: No that's not fit my application needs. The application has links to traverse between some other recursive components too (within the same application). 
The real-time data is much more complex than the example I have provided. In most cases, to render simple data, the recursive component has to pick some specified elements from other deeply nested nodes

Comment: You welcome. I hope someone comes up with a better idea